# Click a aria-label element using xpath

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I am unable to click a button using Xpath and Selenium, in this case the aria-label has a unique date which make it perfect to distinguish among some other buttons from a calendar.

> This is the HTML code for the button that display the day 5 and the
>   price for that day.

---

```html
<button type="button" class="CalendarDay__button" aria-label="Choose sunday, february 4 2018 as your check-in date. It's available." tabindex="0"><div class="calendar-day"><div class="day">4</div><div class="flybondi font-p fare-price"><span>$728*</span></div></div></button>
<button type="button" class="CalendarDay__button" aria-label="Choose monday, february 5 2018 as your check-in date. It's available." tabindex="0"><div class="calendar-day"><div class="day">5</div><div class="flybondi font-p fare-price"><span>$728*</span></div></div></button>
```

---

#Let say I want to click february 5 2018, I tried

```
dtd0_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'CalendarDay__button') and (@aria-label, 'Choose monday, February 5 2018 as your check-in date. It's available') ]")
dtd0_button.Click()
```

what is wrong with this approach and I receive the following message 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'Click' if I can Click for any date in the calendar on the web page.

Comment: Maybe try to use chrome dev tools, selecting the button in the source panel, then try `monitorEvents($0)` in console panel to figure out what's going on with events

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of errors with your xpath, which make it invalid:

1. First of all, you have to state `contains` before each condition:

   ```
   "//button[contains(@attribute1, \"content1\") and contains(@attribute2, \"content2\")]"
   ```
2. The `'` inside your xpath isn't escaped. Try the following:

   ```
   "//button[contains(@class,\"CalendarDay__button\") and contains(@aria-label,\"Choose monday, february 5 2018 as your check-in date. It's available.\")]"
   ```

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, Unfortunately I still get the same message:      dtd0_button.Click()

AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'Click'

Comment: @Petit I've edited my answer. It seems that the problem was with the single quote with the `contains`. Please re-check it!

Comment: besides GalAbra's changes, you probably need to use the method "click()", lower-case "c"

Comment: Great it finally works!! thank you guys I was really stucked with this.